# How to represent only the hour part of a date in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a CSV file representing a daily schedule, e.g.

```
1, a, b, 10:00, 12:00
```

meaning that trip 1 from `a` to `b` departs daily at 10:00 and arrives at 12:00.

I need to load this data into a Pandas data frame and work on it conveniently, e.g. find trips between given hours or sort by departure time.

What is the recommended way to represent only the hour and minutes portion of a date in Pandas?

Comment: If dtype space is not an issue then you could just store them as `datetime64[ns]`, otherwise just convert to minutes and store as ints

Answer (score 2):

I would just store it as a time object. You'll be able to sort / slice based on other time object (more convenient than storing as one column for H, one for Min).

ex :

```
import datetime as dt
t0 = dt.time(hour=12, minute=10)
print t0.hour

12
```

It should be quite straightforward to get time objects into a dataframe (load them as string, then use an apply to transform into a time object)

let me know if you need help for that.

Answer (score 0):

If have a file like this one:

**test.csv**

```
trip,from,to,start,end
1,a,b,10:00,12:00
2,d,c,09:00,10:00
```

You can import it with:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[3, 4])
>>> df
      from  to   start     end
trip                          
1        a   b   10:00   12:00
2        d   c   09:00   10:00
```

Then you can query it like:

```
>>> df[df['start'] > '9:30']
     from to               start                 end
trip                                                
1       a  b 2015-01-26 10:00:00 2015-01-26 12:00:00
```

Alternatively just work with the hours as integers:

```
>>> df['hour'] = df['start'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
>>> df
     from to               start                 end  hour
trip                                                      
1       a  b 2015-01-26 10:00:00 2015-01-26 12:00:00    10
2       d  c 2015-01-26 09:00:00 2015-01-26 10:00:00     9
```

Comment: This maps '10:00' to today's 10:00. You've got a problem if you process different files on different days and store the dataframes for further processing.